# Optional custom column rule. Laravel 5 validation rules

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, validationrules

I want to amend rules in my API request validation. This request is to update a `travel_experience` model instance.

These are the current rules:

```
protected $rules = [
    'city_id'            => 'exists:cities,id',
    'country_id'         => 'exists:countries,id',
```

Basically I want to make `city_id` and `country_id` ***optional***. Which means they ***might*** or ***might not*** exist in the request, if they exist, they ***cannot be null*** and must have an ***ID*** value for city or country.

In short, if they don't exist, then there value should remain the same in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-nullable):

```
protected $rules = [
    'city_id'            => 'nullable|exists:cities,id',
    'country_id'         => 'nullable|exists:countries,id',
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Laravel you're using, you should be able to use the `nullable` validation rule:

```
protected $rules = [
    'city_id'            => 'nullable|exists:cities,id',
    'country_id'         => 'nullable|exists:countries,id',
```